# slideUp is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

following is my code. slideDown is working fine , but slideUp is not working. what is the mistake in my code.

```
var a=0;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#login").click(function(){

    if (a==0){
            $("#banner").slideDown("slow");
            a=1;
        } else {
            $("#banner").slideUp("slow");
            a=0;
        }
    }); 

});
```

Comment: consider making a [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use the [slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) function within jquery?

> Description: Display or hide the matched elements with a sliding
>   motion.

Answer (score 2):

I just tried your code in jsfiddle.net and it works perfect (slideUP and slideDown)
[Test it](http://jsfiddle.net/Y5dH2/6/)

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the [slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) function to achieve your result:

```
$(function() {
  $("#login").click(function() {
      $("#banner").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

However, your code looks like it should work, unless `a` is modified elsewhere (which is entirely possible since it's a global variable), if you wish to continue to use slideUp and slideDown try correcting the scope of a (and possibly giving it a more meaningful name) like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var isUp = true
  $("#login").click(function(){
    if (isUp){
      $("#banner").slideDown("slow");
      isUp = false
    } else {
      $("#banner").slideUp("slow");
      isUp = true;
    }
  }); 
});
```

Comment: i am using the same code mentioned above, but result is the same. slideDown is working fine , but slideUp is not working.

Comment: @asifhameed Please post more code then - see http://jsfiddle.net/8SZtd/ and http://jsfiddle.net/8SZtd/1/ for jsfiddles of above code working fine.